# Understand why opencv's KNearest gives these results

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, knn

Below is the code I run in Python, when `K` = `1`, the output looks correct,
But why when `K` = `3` the result is `4` and not `5`, then there is a row that matches exactly what we were looking for?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

trainFeaturesData = [
    [2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3],
    [4,4,4,4],
    [5,5,5,5],
    [6,6,6,6],
    [7,7,7,7],
]
trainFeatures = np.array(trainFeaturesData, dtype = np.float32)

trainLabelsData = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];
trainLabels = np.array(trainLabelsData, dtype = np.float32)

knn = cv.ml.KNearest_create()
knn.train(trainFeatures, cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, trainLabels)

testFeatureData = [[ 5, 5, 5, 5, ]]
testFeature = np.array(testFeatureData, dtype = np.float32)

for k in [1, 3]:
    print("------------ k = {} --------------\n".format(k));
    ret, results, neighbours ,dist = knn.findNearest(testFeature, k)
    print( "result:     {}\n".format(results) )
    print( "neighbours: {}\n".format(neighbours) )
    print( "distance:   {}\n".format(dist) )
```

Output:

```
------------ k = 1 --------------

result:     [[5.]]

neighbours: [[5.]]

distance:   [[0.]]

------------ k = 3 --------------

result:     [[4.]] <= Why??

neighbours: [[5. 4. 6.]]

distance:   [[0. 4. 4.]]
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the docs? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html#a312f975c24725b57200e221a97474b45 it does return the neighbors and their distances in the parameters, but in the results variable it either returns the mean of the k neighbors (regression model) or the maximum voting (classification model), so result does not use the actual distances at all. Just use the first value from neighbors to get the 1-nearest ;)

Comment: For clarification: I guess your knn is a classification model. Since in your 3-nn there are 3 different classes samples, the majority voting can't decide. I guess if the [6,6,6,6] would be class 5, then there were 2 samples of class 5 and 1 sample of class 4 in the 3-nn and the class 5 would win the majority voting. But maybe I am wrong. If I implemented a majority voting, I would choose the min distance sample in the case of a draw. Either opencv has chosen a different strategy, or I am just wrong with all the guessing ;)